# Parse on "\" (backslash) and convert to uppercase the domain

Tags: vb.net, string, parsing

I would like to take something like this:

```
domainB\bsmith
domainA\djones
```

and convert it to something like this:

```
DOMAINA\bsmith
DOMAINB\djones
```

This is the code that I have thus far:

```
 arrUsers(I) = arrUsers(I).Substring(0, arrUsers(I).IndexOf("\")).ToUpper + arrUsers(I).Substring(arrUsers(I).IndexOf("\"))
```

I would like this to be a little easier to read and understand. Is there a better more sustainable to way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `String.Split` and recombine:

```
Dim parts() As String = arrUsers(I).Split("\"C)
arrUsers(I) = parts(0).ToUpper() + "\" + parts(1)
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for...much cleaner.